# Функция конфликтует с PDO

Tags: php, pdo

при попытке создать функцию внутри дочернего класса PDO, вылазит ошибка Method 'PDO_::prepare()' is not compatible with method 'PDO::prepare()'. С Query та же проблема.

```
class PDO_ extends PDO {
  
        function prepare($sql) {
        $stmt = parent :: prepare($sql, array(
        PDO :: ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS => array('PDOStatement_')
        )); 
        return $stmt; 
        }  
     
        function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $stmt = $this -> prepare($sql); 
        $stmt -> execute($params); 
        return $stmt; 
        }  

        }
```

Comment: давно заглядывали в документацию  PDO prepare и PDO query?  видели какие у них параметры?